# Node js http request: Variable in Options

Tags: node.js, http, variables, request

how can I pass a variable to the requests options?

```
    var test = 'name';
    var options = {
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'someurl',
        headers: {
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        form: {
            test: 'Test01',  //<- this should be the variable, not the name of the key
            description: '\'\'' 
        }
    };
```

I need to set these key-names dynamically via some variables, but all Node won't accept those and instead will use 'test' as the name of the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you should use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)

```
options.form[test] = 'Test01';
```

so the full code should be

```js
    var test = 'name';
    var options = {
        method: 'PUT',
        url: 'someurl',
        headers: {
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        form: {
            description: '\'\'' 
        }
    };

    options.form[test] = 'Test01';
    
    console.log(options);
```